# Resize Table Range

Tags: vba, excel

This section of code is intended to resize a table in order to add a new row of data input from a UserForm. Currently when I run the code, I get:

> Error 9 - Subscript out of range

On the line:

```
Set tbl1 = sht1.ListObjects("LogTable")
```

This is the full code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Start button
'Log start time as the time the button is clicked

Dim EmptyRow, LastRow   As Long
Dim sPath               As String
Dim tbl1, tbl2          As Range

'Find next empty row based on first column
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Log")
Set tbl1 = sht1.ListObjects("LogTable")

LastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
EmptyRow = LastRow + 1

tbl1.Resize Range("A2:E" & EmptyRow)

sht1.Cells(EmptyRow, 1).Value = Now
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Suggests you don't have a table going by that name. But tables resize automatically anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Dim tbl1 As ListObject
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sht1 = wb.Sheets("Log")
    Set tbl1 = sht1.ListObjects("LogTable")

    tbl1.ListRows.Add
```

Please note:

Your code contains incorrect declarations: `EmptyRow` and `tbl1` are declared as Variant, which is not what you intended (it seems). It's a common VBA mistake – assuming that type declaration applies to all variables on the line. It does not. The easiest way to avoid it is to always declare one variable per line.

Also, `tbl1` and `tbl2` should be declared as tables (`ListObject`), not ranges.